# Why are some questions highlighted yellow?

Tags: discussion, design

I have noticed for a while now that occasionally questions on SO will have a yellow highlight, like these on the `Newest` section

[image: yellow highlighting]

These highlighted questions also appear in all the other methods of sorting questions, such as `Unanswered` or `Votes`.

The only thing I could think that it is for answered or unanswered questions, but this picture shows that cannot be, nor with unviewed or unvoted questions.

What does this yellow highlighting mean, what is it's significance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your screenshot, they're all [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) questions that are highlighted, and [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) is one of your watched tags. So it's highlighting questions in tags you're watching, which makes sense.